# Start Google Assistant / Now with text search query

Tags: android, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is it possible to start Google Assistant / Now programmatically with a string parameter and make it output voice?

E.g., start it by passing the string "what's the weather" as a parameter and make it respond by voice "the weather is ...".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you can try API.AI (https://api.ai/). It's web based easy platform. Tutorial video can be found here: https://youtu.be/9SUAuy9OJg4. There are other platforms too like Node.js
More information in https://developers.google.com/actions/.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the APIs. What I mean is that I want to start Google Assistant with a predefined question from my Android app. For example, the user taps a button "Ask Google about the weather" and my app starts Google Assistant with this query and Google Assistant answers with voice "the weather is..." without any other user interaction.

Comment: OK. I said ´"I'm not sure what you mean". I don't have more ideas. Good luck finding answer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's currently impossible.